# Sonarqube plugin not working on maven build

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have created a plugin based on [this example](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-rules-examples/tree/master/java-custom-rules). I add some log to check if everything is loaded well.
When I start the SonarQube server, the main class is loaded and all Rules are loaded:

> Loading Plugin: org.sonar.samples.java.MyJavaRulesPlugin Adding Rule:
>   org.sonar.samples.java.checks.SpringControllerRequestMappingEntityRule
>   Adding Rule: org.sonar.samples.java.checks.AvoidAnnotationRule Adding
>   Rule: org.sonar.samples.java.checks.AvoidBrandInMethodNamesRule Adding
>   Rule: org.sonar.samples.java.checks.AvoidMethodDeclarationRule Adding
>   Rule: org.sonar.samples.java.checks.AvoidSuperClassRule Adding Rule:
>   org.sonar.samples.java.checks.AvoidUnmodifiableListRule Adding Rule:
>   org.sonar.samples.java.checks.MyCustomSubscriptionRule Adding Rule:
>   org.sonar.samples.java.checks.SecurityAnnotationMandatoryRule

But when I execute the local maven build point to my server: `mvn sonar:sonar` only the plugin is loaded.

> Loading Plugin: org.sonar.samples.java.MyJavaRulesPlugin

This is my `Dockerfile` to build my server:

```
FROM openjdk:8-alpine

ENV SONAR_VERSION=7.1 \
    SONARQUBE_HOME=/opt/sonarqube \
    # Database configuration
    # Defaults to using H2
    SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar \
    SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar \
    SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=

# Http port
EXPOSE 9000

RUN addgroup -S sonarqube && adduser -S -G sonarqube sonarqube

RUN set -x \
    && apk add --no-cache gnupg unzip \
    && apk add --no-cache libressl wget \
    && apk add --no-cache su-exec \
    && apk add --no-cache bash \

    # pub   2048R/D26468DE 2015-05-25
    #       Key fingerprint = F118 2E81 C792 9289 21DB  CAB4 CFCA 4A29 D264 68DE
    # uid                  sonarsource_deployer (Sonarsource Deployer) <infra@sonarsource.com>
    # sub   2048R/06855C1D 2015-05-25
    && gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys F1182E81C792928921DBCAB4CFCA4A29D26468DE \

    && mkdir /opt \
    && cd /opt \
    && wget -O sonarqube.zip --no-verbose https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonarqube/sonarqube-$SONAR_VERSION.zip \
    && wget -O sonarqube.zip.asc --no-verbose https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonarqube/sonarqube-$SONAR_VERSION.zip.asc \
    && gpg --batch --verify sonarqube.zip.asc sonarqube.zip \
    && unzip sonarqube.zip \
    && mv sonarqube-$SONAR_VERSION sonarqube \
    && chown -R sonarqube:sonarqube sonarqube \
    && rm sonarqube.zip* \
    && rm -rf $SONARQUBE_HOME/bin/*

ADD target/java-custom-rules-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar      $SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/plugins/

VOLUME "$SONARQUBE_HOME/data"

WORKDIR $SONARQUBE_HOME
COPY run.sh $SONARQUBE_HOME/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/run.sh"]
```

How can I get my plugin validating my code on maven build?

Comment: Did you add your rules to the quality profile?

Comment: No, how can I configure that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate your rules in the quality profile binded to the project. You can enabled them in the following two ways (tested on SonarQube 7.1):

1. find rules and activate them:

   - open Rules tab
   - search for a rule which you would like to enable
   - open the rule
   - click the `Activate` button next to Quality Profiles
   - choose a quality profile to which the rule should be added

[image: steps]

2. find quality profiles and activate rules:

   - open Quality Profiles tab
   - choose a quality profile to which rules should be added
   - click Total Inactive rules
   - activate rules (you can also the use `Search for rules...` filed to filter results)

[image: steps]

Read more about quality profiles on [SonarQube wiki](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles).